# Simple jquery UI autocomplete page does not work

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am a beginner in jquery programming: My apologies if my code is bad.

I have a simple html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = [];
    var items = {};
    $.getJSON('testjson.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            arr.push(value);
        });
        arr.join(',');
        items = {source: arr};
    });
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete(items);
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="Heading" >
<h2 align="center">Client Browser</h2>
</div>  
<input id="autocomplete" size="100" align="middle"/>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my testjson.json file:

```
{
"1":"One",
"2":"Two",
"3":"Three"
}
```

When I run the html file using Altova XML spy, I get proper output. But when I open it in browser (running through XAMP server), this is what I get in firefox console:

"this.source is not a function" in jquery-ui.min.js line 5

However it does work if I directly pass JS object to autocomplete function like for instance, the following code works:

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({source:["One", "Two", "Three"]});
```

I am not able to understand where the issue is since items contain the same object. What am I not doing correct here?

Comment: One issue is that your json request will complete at an arbitrary time in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you initialize your autocomplete not after successful Ajax request but at the same time as the request is executed.

You should place the corresponding line inside the success handler:

```
$.getJSON('testjson.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        arr.push(value);
    });
    arr.join(',');               // BTW, this line doesn't make any sense
    items = {source: arr};

    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete(items);   // <-- place here
});
```

Comment: This seems like the likely issue to me as well. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try moving this line:

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete(items);
```

into your getJSON callback. i.e.

```
$.getJSON('testjson.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        arr.push(value);
    });
    arr.join(',');
    items = {source: arr};
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete(items);
});
```